# How to setup counters for target-counters

Tags: css, css-paged-media

In paged media, the CSS property [`target-counters`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#the-target-counter-and-target-counters-v) can be used to include multiple counters. The spec gives the following example (simplified):

```
a::after {
 content: "see section " target-counters(attr(href, url), section, ".")
}
```

that should output something like `(see section 1.3.5)`.

How would I set up the `section` counter?

Comment: didn't know that something like this exists, it was a good read thanks :)

Comment: It seems like `target-counters` is what I am after but this doesn't seem to work in any browser (for me at least!) Is there a way to get Chrome to process these? perhaps with an experimental flag or mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Generated Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#nested) (for non-paged content, too):

> Counters are "self-nesting", in the sense that re-using a counter in a
>   child element automatically creates a new instance of the counter.

Therefore, you can just write

```
<style type="text/css">    
section {counter-increment: section;}
</style>

<section id="foo">
<h1>Root level</h1>
    <section id="bar">
    <h2>Sub Level</h2>
    </section>
</section>
```

There is no way to use nested counters if your element tree is flat (as in `<h1>Root</h1><h2>Sub</h2>`).