# CSS target-counter attribute not recognised

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use `target-counter` to describe references.

I found out about it from a [List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/boom) on making a book with HTML/CSS. There's only [one other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829395/how-to-setup-counters-for-target-counters) and it didn't help me.

The attribute `target-counter` is not recognised by Chrome, Firefox or Opera, but it's mentioned in the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#cross-references) and I can't find any other docs that say whether it's supported or not. So I can't tell if it's my code or the browser that's to blame.

You can see the code on [this Dabblet snippet](http://dabblet.com/gist/1923000), or look at the snippets below.

My HTML:

```
<h1 id="foo">Root level</h1>
<p><a href="#bar">linking to bar</a> and stuff</p>

<h1 id="bar">Second heading</h1>

<h2 id="sub">Subhead</h2>
<p>Hey there <a href="#foo">with a link to foo</a></p>
```

And CSS:

```
h1 {
    counter-increment: section;
}
h1::before {
    content: counter(section) ". ";
}
a::after {
    content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), section);
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`target-counter()` is a **CSS3 function**, not a CSS2 function. It says so in the document that you link to!

Since that function is part of a long-forgotten CSS3 Generated Content module draft, you won't find any browser support for it yet as current implementations only support the [level 2 Generated Content spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html). This means that current browsers only support the use of the level 2 `attr()` function with the `content` property on the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Additionally, the ALA article you link to mentions [Prince](http://www.princexml.com), a piece of software for turning Web documents into paged documents with CSS. As I mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6811991/106224) (where the question references the same ALA article!), the print styles you're referring to may only be supported and intended for use by Prince, not the print functions of any Web browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I should've noticed that it was CSS3. Regarding Prince, I thought that the `target-counter` function was available in the browser, not just for printed/paged media.

Comment: Well, notice that it's defined in the Generated Content for Paged Media specification ;)

Comment: Hello from the future. Is this available in CSS3 as it stands today?

Comment: @Ben Davis: It's still in GCPM, but I have no idea if it's implemented anywhere.